# Modular Arithmetic.......

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that a duplicate of this question is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836754/modulus-number-theory-basic) ,but i am still
posting this because the post contain only hint.I solved this using myself ,and
i want to verify it.

### Question

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are integers,  **$a ≡  4 (mod 13)$**, and
> **$b ≡ 9 (mod 13)$**.
> Find the integer $c$ with $0 ≤ c ≤ 12$ such that

1. $c ≡ 9\,\,a (\text {mod} \,\,13)$

### My attempt

Given

$\Rightarrow$ **$a ≡  4 (mod 13)$**

we can write it using symmetric as,

$\Rightarrow$ **$4 ≡  a (mod 13)$**

$\Rightarrow$ **$b ≡ 9 (mod 13)$**.

We can write above as

$\Rightarrow$ **$4*b ≡ 9a (mod 13)$**.

and our question is

$c ≡ 9\,\,a (\text {mod} \,\,13)$

I am stuck here , any way to move forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute, using $a\equiv 4\bmod 13$, that
$$
9a\equiv 9\cdot 4=36\equiv 10\bmod 13.
$$
hence we have $c=10$. We do not need to know $b$, by the way.

Comment: we can choose $a$ as $4+13$ ..why we choosen $a=4$? so that $c$ lies within the asked range?

Comment: If we write $\equiv$, then $4\equiv 4+13k$ for all $k$, so this makes no difference. And I wrote $9a\equiv 9\cdot 4$ and not $9a=9\cdot 4$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it legal to replace ≡ with = sign? How you replace c≡9a(mod13) with  c=9a(mod13)

Comment: Almost. We have that $c \equiv 9a \bmod 13$ is equivalent to the equation $c=9a$ in the ring $\Bbb Z/13$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$9a\equiv 36 \equiv -3 \; (13) $$

$$\implies c\equiv -3 \;(13 ) $$
$$\implies c=10$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it legal to replace ≡ with = sign? How you replace c≡9a(mod13) with  c=9a(mod13)

Comment: @Avra yes, in terms of class.

Comment: Thank you again. Can you please clarify what in terms of class means?

Comment: $c=10$ means class of $ c$ is equal to class of $10$.